# How to write a Typescript type-safe event to pass to onclick function in React-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make it typesafe, but the compiler built successfully.  What did I miss?

In action.ts

```
export type AnActionType = ( index: number, value?: string ) => ReduxAsyncAction
```

In component.tsx

```
const changeHandler = (value, action : AnActionType ) => {
  action(value); //expects to complain on missing arg
  action(value, 1); // expects to complain on arg types
}

<Select onchange={ value => changeHandler(value, action ) } />
```

How should I write the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `:number` for `value` in your signature like so :

```js
const changeHandler = (value: number, action: AnActionType ): void => {
    action(value); //expects to complain on missing arg
    action(value, 1); // expects to complain on arg types
}
```